# How to Delay Between Typed Characters with Selenium Sendkeys

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I'm using an actions chain to type in an input, but I realize that I get duplicate characters, is this because I didn't delay?  how can i solve this?  for example look at this:

```
big_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt porta ex, vitae luctus arcu pharetra quis. Nullam id congue risus, at lacinia nulla. Vestibulum at nunc ut ante fermentum placerat sit amet non libero. In augue ipsum, commodo a accumsan a, tincidunt sit amet magna. Nullam vel risus vel sem auctor pharetra. Sed euismod porta metus vel imperdiet. Etiam ultricies tempor nulla, vel scelerisque ipsum elementum vel. Curabitur ultricies orci non lectus tempor, nec malesuada leo ornare. Curabitur vehicula eros sit amet tincidunt pharetra. Curabitur dictum euismod porta. Pellentesque congue accumsan rutrum. Praesent a lectus sit amet odio auctor sagittis. Phasellus eu posuere urna. Donec fermentum diam eu est blandit auctor. Aliquam mauris dolor, aliquam eget lacus quis, consequat lobortis massa. Integer suscipit elementum ornare. Fusce dapibus id lorem vitae vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed ullamcorper mollis risus, et hendrerit tellus interdum in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae"    
big_text2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor dolor sed turpis volutpat, et dictum risus tempus. Fusce tristique congue purus, vitae sollicitudin ligula auctor eu. Donec dolor leo, aliquet in interdum id, lobortis nec nisi. Pellentesque ornare nunc semper arcu dapibus finibus. Pellentesque gravida pretium placerat. Fusce vulputate lectus eu arcu pretium vestibulum. Nam ac est eget sem blandit rhoncus. Nulla viverra sodales accumsan. Nunc mollis molestie libero, in interdum massa dictum vel. In non interdum nisl. Donec libero mi, condimentum id odio id, posuere suscipit orci. Curabitur ultrices turpis id neque aliquet, id luctus justo tristique. Integer finibus, tellus lobortis ultricies convallis, elit diam semper nisl, eu commodo mi quam vel lacus. Proin porta tortor facilisis ante sagittis tristique. Duis erat nisl, sollicitudin ut mollis vulputate, rhoncus nec sapien. Aliquam laoreet enim eros, ac rutrum lorem aliquam vel. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Integer cursus quam sit amet ligula bibendum, id tincidunt arcu convallis. Integer fermentum justo velit, eget porta diam venenatis ut. Etiam dignissim eu felis eget rutrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque odio massa, tincidunt nec ex sed, sagittis rutrum neque. Donec sit amet magna tortor. Etiam placerat, eros venenatis condimentum pellentesque, nibh erat ullamcorper dui, a bibendum augue ligula at leo."
send_js_command.send_keys(big_text, Keys.ENTER)                                           
send_js_command.pause(5)                      
send_js_command.send_keys(big_text2, Keys.ENTER)
```

I notice that sometimes he didn't enter the first text and start the second one, or he writes some duplicate characters in the first text and then goes to the second, how do I solve this?  sendkeys is slow will i have to slow down even more?

How can I solve this problem but make my script faster in return?  I thought about giving Ctrl c + Ctrl v, but the text is inside a variable, how will I give ctrl + c?

**Note the code above was just a small example, in my code this is what happens. For some reasons I need to use sendkeys so I can't use `execute_script` or anything like that, my only option is to use sendkeys**

Comment: If you need to delay the sending of keys, have you tried using just ```time.sleep(5)```?

Comment: @Loons22 The same thing happens

Comment: `send_js_command.clear()` and then you should trigger `.send_keys`

Comment: @YaDav MaNish I'm using this on the devtools console

Comment: @cruisepandeyBut it shouldn't happen, because if send_keys gives enter it clears the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay we understand that you do not want to use `execute_script` and would want to stick with `send_keys`

this can be achieve with `CTRL + c` to copy and `CTRL + v` to paste.

and below we can simulate the same in `Selenium` : (I have taken **google search bar** as an example and `pyperclip` to `copy string to clipboard`).

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
big_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt porta ex, vitae luctus arcu pharetra quis. Nullam id congue risus, at lacinia nulla. Vestibulum at nunc ut ante fermentum placerat sit amet non libero. In augue ipsum, commodo a accumsan a, tincidunt sit amet magna. Nullam vel risus vel sem auctor pharetra. Sed euismod porta metus vel imperdiet. Etiam ultricies tempor nulla, vel scelerisque ipsum elementum vel. Curabitur ultricies orci non lectus tempor, nec malesuada leo ornare. Curabitur vehicula eros sit amet tincidunt pharetra. Curabitur dictum euismod porta. Pellentesque congue accumsan rutrum. Praesent a lectus sit amet odio auctor sagittis. Phasellus eu posuere urna. Donec fermentum diam eu est blandit auctor. Aliquam mauris dolor, aliquam eget lacus quis, consequat lobortis massa. Integer suscipit elementum ornare. Fusce dapibus id lorem vitae vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed ullamcorper mollis risus, et hendrerit tellus interdum in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae"
time.sleep(2)
pyperclip.copy(big_text)
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
```